# How to concat or copy files from source to destination depending on if destination file already exists?

Tags: ant, copy, concatenation, fileset

Using Ant, I need to copy files to a destination directory, and concatenate to the destination if the file already exists.

Below is the source and destination directory structure.

```
src_dir/  
    /values1/    
        strings.xml
        id.xml
    /values2/
        strings2.xml

dest_dir/  
    /values1/
        strings.xml
        id.xml
```

So in this case, I want `strings.xml` from `src_dir/values1` to be appended to `strings.xml` in `dest_dir/values1`, and same with `id.xml`.

Also, since `strings2.xml` doesn't exist in `dest_dir/values2`, I would want to just create a `values2` dir in `dest_dir` and copy `strings2.xml` over.

I have been making a mess trying to parse directories from src to build a destination for concat, but I am over my head.

Comment: If its definitive list, then I think you can use available ant task to check existence of file on destination & based on which you can use copy or concat -with append=true ant task to achieve this. And I think ant is not intelligent enough to handle recursive directory mapping!